# javascript closure and ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, closures

I know that async things will change the context, and we need use closure to make it work, but I couldn't deal with the next example:

```
var loadTemplate = function(options){

    var def = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        data: { id: options.id },
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(template){
        // HERE template's id !== options.id
        $('body').append(template);
        def.resolve();
    });

    return def.promise();
};
```

I call `loadTempate` with different IDs and several times. But the first success ajax result will have the loaded `template`, but it is not equall to `options.id` passed to it.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

I have *loader*:

```
var loader = function(){

    var _load = function(options){

        $.when(loadTemplate(options), loadAnotherStuff(options))
         .done(function(res){
            // a lot of work here
        });

    };

    return {
        load: _load
    }

};
```

Then I call that from the page:

```
Loader.load({ id: 1});
Loader.load({ id: 2});
Loader.load({ id: 3});
```

Comment: If the object that is being passed in being changed? Very basic sample: `var foo = { id : 1 }; loadTemplate(foo); foo.id=2;`

Comment: Sounds like a server issue returning the wrong template - check the query call with your debugger

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't this a server side issue? Are you sure your server is returning the correct template?

Comment: Can you include the code that is calling this function?

Comment: Please see my updates

Comment: Shouldn't `dev.resolve()` be `def.resolve()` ? and also `load: _load` should be `load: load` ... Why not copy/paste parts instead of rewriting them for the question.. you might not be posting something that could be the actual problem this way..

Comment: You are right. That's typo.. my fault.

Comment: Well, If I'll copy the whole src it will be too large.